# Two PR2 simulation in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on ROS Fuerte, I am using PR2 simulations in gazebo with the *pr2_gazebo* package,

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

I wish to work on two PR2 robots, I tried to add a second robot with the following line in the *pr2_empty_world.launch*.

```
  <!-- start pr2 robot -->
  <include file="$(find pr2_gazebo)/launch/pr2.launch"/>
```

Which gave the following error;

```
roslaunch file contains multiple nodes named [/spawn_pr2_model].
Please check all <node> 'name' attributes to make sure they are unique.
Also check that $(anon id) use different ids.
```

Apparently it is a trivial issue, and I have been tinkering with launch files but that has not solved the issue. Any help here would be most welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52540/two-pr2-simulation-in-gazebo/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

Nodes must have a unique name when roslaunched Take a look into pr2.launch to see how the launch is exactly done, you'll see that you're roslauching twice the same node with the same name.

---

Originally posted by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) with karma: 697 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-01-16**:
@Erwan R. I get the point, but how do I rectify it ??? I would wish to have 2 nodes as /spawn_pr2_model_1 and /spawn_pr2_model_2 !!! How do I do it ?

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2013-01-17**:
Write your own pr2_2robot_empty_world.launch inspired by the original one. You'll have to check the content of the included pr2.launch and, for example, paste it twice into your file with different names for nodes.

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-01-17**:
Erwan R. Easy said ! but I am trying ! .... :-D

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2013-01-21**:
Go deeper : in pr2.launch are included pr2_no_controller.launch where spawn_pr2_model node is launched. You can start from this point and duplicate the node line. Be careful about the -model name too. gazebo needs unique name for each object. Please be more precise if there is still a problem.

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2013-01-21**:
Go deeper : in pr2.launch are included pr2_no_controller.launch where spawn_pr2_model node is launched